# Creating output files from Drupal 6

Tags: 6, files

I need to produce PDF/HTML output from my Drupal 6 app; is there a "Drupal way" to create a template with variables and then substitute them when the output is rendered or do i have to realize it by hand?

**EDITED**

Data is not on a node, but need to select from a non-drupal table

Comment: You need to generate a pdf from the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Views, you could try the [Views PDF](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) module.

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field
>   of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the
>   administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is
>   added.

Or perhaps the [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module if you're just creating a PDF from a node.

> This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly
>   versions of any node:
>
> - Printer-friendly version (webpage format) (at
>     www.example.com/print/nid)
> - PDF version (at
>     www.example.com/printpdf/nid)
> - Send by email (at
>     www.example.com/printmail/nid)

**Edit**:

If you're willing to do a little legwork, you can use the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module to expose your non-Drupal table to Views, and then use the previously mentions [Views PDF](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Print Email and PDF](http://drupal.org/project/print) module ?
This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly versions of any node:

- Printer-friendly version (webpage format) (at
  www.example.com/print/nid)
- PDF version (at www.example.com/printpdf/nid)
- Send by email (at    www.example.com/printmail/nid)